# Problem with Fancybox. Iframe works only for the first link on the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am testing Fancybox for Iframes and I noticed that on my Wordpress blog (and I guess everywhere else) the iframe is opened only for the first link on my home page.
I have added the id attribute to all of the links though.

Any ideas why is that and how to correct it?
Below is the code. I only changed the name to popup and set to all links id="popup". On the examples page it also uses id, but on one link only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#popup").fancybox({
            'width'             : '75%',
            'height'            : '75%',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 1st add some code 2nd i think it should be a class that has the same name not an ID! ID is ought to be UNIQUE so try to change id into class and then change the selector of the fancy box

Comment: @Itroubs Hi there, I have updated the question but what I did is exactly from their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs **must** be unique. If your existing code is something like

```
<a href="whatever" id="popup">Link 1</a>
<a href="whateverelse" id="popup">Link 2</a>
```

Change it instead to be

```
<a href="whatever" class="popup">Link 1</a>
<a href="whateverelse" class="popup">Link 2</a>
```

Then, adjust your Javascript to be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.popup").fancybox({
            'width'             : '75%',
            'height'            : '75%',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe'
        });
    });
</script>
```

The reason why using the code from their documentation isn't working for you is because their documentation is dealing with *a single link only*, not a group of links.

Comment: Thank you sir! It worked. Is there any list with the transition effects?

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing there is adding one fancybox to one entity with the id popup. if you want multiple `<a>` tags to have their own fancybox then you have to either do what you did for efery  tag with a different id OR you give them the same class with different "rel".

see this [example](http://www.ridgi-pad.de/galerie.html)